# Low Level Hook / SetWindowsHookEx lParam Auto-Repeat?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, low-level

Reading here:
[How is keyboard auto-repeat implemented on a Windows PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876852/how-is-keyboard-auto-repeat-implemented-on-a-windows-pc?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I understand that low level keyboard hook does't receive auto-repeat count :/

> Note that the low level keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL) does not
>   receive the repeat count.

But why?? o.O

The way I used to extract the auto-repeat count using windows messages:
`int repeatCount = (lParam & KF_REPEAT);`

But it doesn't work for some reason when I use the `SetWindowsHookEx` hooking the `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`.

I want to filter auto-repeat for the `Space` key while using the global hook. Is there a way doing that? Possibly a creative way to determine if the key down press is auto-repeated(i.e held down)?

Sample code:

```
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbd = *(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)(lParam);
        if (kbd.vkCode == VK_SPACE && !(lParam & KF_REPEAT))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why so low level? Don't you have a library or framework that already handles this for you?

Comment: I'm writing a custom widget in a GUI that filters certain keys on the system level while it's being active, so even ALT + TAB won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that low level keyboard hook does't receive auto-repeat count ... But why??

Because the auto-repeat counter simply *does not exist* at the low level. At that level, you are getting events from the keyboard itself. Key down, key up, that is it. The keyboard is not in control of the counter.

At *a higher level*, when the system is processing those low level events from the keyboard and generating key messages for distribution to apps, the system runs its own timer to manage the repeat counter and create the corresponding key messages whenever the counter is incremented.

> I want to filter auto-repeat for the `Space` key while using the global hook. Is there a way doing that?

In a *low level* hook, you will have to run your own timer, just like the system does.

Otherwise, use a *higher level* message hook instead of a keyboard hook.

Comment: Thank you @Remy! That already helps a lot to understand of possible solutions. One question if I may ask, when you say `use a message hook instead` you mean: `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, WndProc, nullptr, 0)` ? I don't get any messages to my `WndProc` when I use that one.

Comment: Btw, I don't know why would my thread attract negative reputation :/

Comment: @MartinBrooker yes, that is the hook I was referring to. Do you have a message loop in the thread that instalation the hook?

Comment: A global `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook does not require a message loop. It requires that the hook procedure resides in a DLL, though, and you can only hook applications with the same bitness as the DLL.